# Does a list contain this symbol?

Tags: quote

I'm confused by the interpretation of `'` in the context of lists of symbols.

The problem is that I'd like to check whether a buffer is in one a list of modes, and I'll use the scratch buffer as my example.

```
(with-current-buffer "*scratch*" major-mode) ;; lisp-interaction-mode
(equal (with-current-buffer "*scratch*" major-mode) 'lisp-interaction-mode) ;; t
```

So far so good.

```
(member (with-current-buffer "*scratch*" major-mode)
        '('lisp-interaction-mode) ;; nil
```

Huh? Trying to simplify this, I ended up with

```
(member 1 '( 1)) ;; (1) - okay, my list syntax seems correct
(member '1 '( '1)) ;; nil - Why doesn't this work? I think this is the issue
```

So how can I make a list of symbols, and then check whether a symbol is in there?

Comment: You may wish to look at `eq` ["*Return t if the two args are the same Lisp object.*"] as compared to `equal`.  And, also have a look at `memq` ["*Return non-nil if ELT is an element of LIST.  Comparison done with ‘eq’.  The value is actually the tail of LIST whose car is ELT.*"] versus `member`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short version: remove the inner quote.

When you quote a list, it leaves the list's contents unevaluated:

```
'(a-symbol "a string" (+ 1 1)) => (a-symbol "a string" (+ 1 1))
```

So: if the list includes symbols, a quoted list will return a
list of symbols.  Here's the rub: [because quoting is so common,
there's a special reader syntax for
it](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Quoting.html): `'`.  So:

```
'kittens        => kittens
(quote kittens) => kittens
```

So, when you quote a list that includes a quoted symbol, what
you're actually producing is:

```
'('kittens) => ((quote kittens))
```

when what you really want is:

```
'(kittens)  => kittens
```

So your comparison looks like:

```
(memq 'kittens '(puppies kittens otters))    => (kittens otters)
(memq 'kittens '('puppies 'kittens 'otters)) => nil
```